# crear un historial de cambios en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Hola tengo un problema no se como podría crear un historial en mi base de datos por ejemplo: tengo un formulario donde registro conductores, a esos conductores yo les asigno su vehículo pero puedo estar intercambiando las asignaciones entonces quiero guardar el historial de esos cambios y posteriormente identificar a que conductor le pertenecía anteriormente un vehículo.

pensé en hacer una tabla conductor donde registro y otra tabla donde al momento de actualizar la primera se me llene la segunda y asi ir tenindo un registro de los cambios efectuados.

he leído que se puede hacer con un trigger o disparadores con el log de mysql pero estoy totalmente perdido en este tema.

con este código actualizo mi la tabla conductor asignándole un vehículo a un nuevo conductor:

```
<?php
$conductor=$_POST['conductor'];
$vehiculo=$_POST['vehiculo'];
$fecha_mod=$_POST['fecha_mod'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die(mysqli_error());

$query2= " UPDATE conductor SET id_conductor = '$conductor', vehiculo = '$vehiculo', fecha_modificacion = '$fecha_mod' WHERE id_conductor  = ' " . $conductor. " ' ";

$resultado=mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die (mysqli_error());    
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

aquí intente crear un trigger después de que se ejecute mi consulta update pero la verdad no se ni como crearlo y donde ponerlo en mi codigo estoy haciendo pruebas:

```
    <?php
    $conductor=$_POST['conductor'];
    $vehiculo=$_POST['vehiculo'];
    $fecha_mod=$_POST['fecha_mod'];

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die(mysqli_error());

    $query2= " UPDATE conductor SET id_conductor = '$conductor', vehiculo = '$vehiculo', fecha_modificacion = '$fecha_mod' WHERE id_conductor  = ' " . $conductor. " ' ";

    $resultado=mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die (mysqli_error()); 

    $trigger="
DELIMITER #
CREATE TRIGGER updateconductor
AFTER INSERT ON conductor FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO historial_conductor (nombre, apellido_pat, apellido_mat, licencia, fecha_vencimiento, vehiculo,fecha_modificacion) VALUES ('new.nombre','new.apellido_pat','new.apellido_mat','new.licenica','new.fecha_vencimiento','new.vehiculo','new.fecha_modificacion')
END"; 

$resultado2=mysqli_query($con, $trigger) or die (mysqli_error()); 
mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un par de puntos a tratar en tu pregunta

## Modelo de datos

Pueden haber varias maneras de resolverlo, creo que la mejor y la que te da más posibilidades es crear 3 tablas.

La relación entre coches y conductores es de M a N. Es decir un coche puede pertenecer a varios conductores (por lo menos con el paso del tiempo) y un conductor puede conducir varios coches (tal vez no a la vez, pero también con el tiempo). Esto es una **"relación de varios a varios"** o **"relación de M a N"** y se modela con 3 tablas:

```
   Coches
______________
PK IdCoche
   Matricula
   Color
   ...
```

```
   Conductores
______________
PK IdConductor
   Nombre
   Apellido1
   Apellido1
   ...
```

```
   RLCochesConductores
______________________
FK IdConductor
FK IdCoche
   FechaAsignacion
   FechaDesignacion
   ...
```

Con estas 3 tablas puedes controlar mas o menos todas las situaciones y te será fácil saber para un coche que conductores ha tenido, un conductor que coches ha conducido, en determinada fecha todas las asignaciones coches-conductor, ...

## Consultas

## Crear, actualizar o eliminar coches o conductores

Con este modelo, cada vez que insertas coches o conductores, no tienes que hacer nada más que insertarlos en su tabla correspondiente.

Igualmente, si tienes que actulizar alguna característica propia del vehículo o del conductor (y solo de esa entidad) tampoco tendrás que hacer nada más. Es decir, si cambias el color de un coche que sigue asignado un conductor (o que no está asignado) solo harás el update en la tabla coches.

Si quieres eliminar un coche o conductor, solo tendrás que hacerlo en la tabla correspondiente, aunque tendrías que comprobar que no tenga un registro activo en la tabla RLCochesConductores, si lo tuviese, tal vez deberías desasignar esa relación (más de esto en un momento)

### Asignar coches a conductores y viceversa

Cuando asignas un coche a un conductor (o al revés) haces un `INSERT` en RLCochesConductores, informando además la FechaAsignación (idealmente un timestamp)

Cuando desasignas un coche de un conductor (o al revés) haces un `UPDATE` informando en RLCochesConductores, informando la FechaDesasignación (también timestamp).

Al asignar un coche o conductor que ya está asignado, tienes que tener en cuenta si puede o no estar asignado al mismo conductor a la vez o no, en función de eso, siempre deberas desasignarlos antes o no.

### Triggers

En este caso concreto yo no te recomendaría usar triggers porque la lógica que hay detrás de cada operación que haces en la tabla es muy dependiente de las necesidades de negocio y te va a ser más fácil implementarlo directamente con consultas directas.

## RLCochesConductores

```
   RLCochesConductores
______________________
IdCoche|IdConductor |FechaAsignado|FechaDesasignado|
Coche1 | Conductor1 |  07ABR2019  |  13MAY2019     |
Coche1 | Conductor2 |  13MAY2019  |                |
Coche2 | Conductor3 |  10MAY2019  |  13MAY2019     |
Coche2 | Conductor4 |  13MAY2019  |  14MAY2019     |
Coche2 | Conductor3 |  14MAY2019  |                |
Coche3 | Conductor5 |  10MAY2019  |  13MAY2019     |
Coche3 | Conductor1 |  13MAY2019  |                |
   ...
```

Ahí ves que el conductor3 tuvo el coche 2 del 10 al 13 de mayo y se lo volviste a asignar el 14, es decir, la fechaAsignación también forma parte de la clave primaria de esta tabla

```
// Sentencias sin ninguna sintaxis particular y donde faltaria hacer las JOIN
// Para conocer el historial de un coche
SELECT * FROM RLCochesConductores WHERE IdCoche = <idCoche>

// Para conocer el historial de un conductor
SELECT * FROM RLCochesConductores WHERE IdConcuctor = <idConductor>

// Para conocer la situación actual de lo que está asignado
SELECT * FROM RLCochesConductores WHERE FechaDesasignado = null

//Situacion entre fecha1 y fecha2
SELECT * FROM RLCochesConductores WHERE FechaAsignado >= <fecha1> AND FechaDesasignado <= <fecha2>
```

Comment: ok muchas gracias si me parece mas adaptable este modelo de tablas relacionales lo intentare como me indica

Comment: Cuando asignas un coche a un conductor (o al revés) haces un INSERT en RLCochesConductores, informando además la FechaAsignación (idealmente un timestamp)

Cuando desasignas un coche de un conductor (o al revés) haces un UPDATE informando en RLCochesConductores, informando la FechaDesasignación (también timestamp).

Comment: si hago todo en esa tabla insert y update voy a estar actualizando mi dato que ya inserte y no me quedara historial por que se modifico un solo dato mas bien tendria que tener una duplicidad para que se quede algun registro no ?

Comment: se me hace mas facil que con un trigger cada vez que reasigne un vehiculo para ese conductor me llene otra tabla con la fecha de modificacion y asi en mi tabla conductor muestro los datos actuales y con mi otra tabla las modificaciones anteriores y ver quien lo tenia asignado antes no ?

Comment: Si reasignas un conductor/coche tendrás que hacer el update y al momento un nuevo insert de la nueva asignación, en ese insert no informarás FechaDesasignación.

Comment: lo que no me queda claro es que en mi tabla RLCochesConductores asigno y desasigno pero por ejemplo conductor 1 tiene el coche 1 el día x y al día siguiente cambio el coche1 a otro conductor2 ese registro ya lo altere como se que conductor lo tenia el dia x

Comment: Te he ampliado la respuesta. La idea es que en esa tabla puedes repetir registros con Coche1 Conductor1, porque el campo FechaAsignacion tambien forma parte de la clave

Comment: muchas gracias por la información ya me quedo un poco mas claro como manejar el modelado de las tablas

Answer (score 1):

disculpen, que modificación se le debe realizar a la base de datos para que me permita agregar registros repetidos en `IdCoche` y `IdCoductor`, por ejemplo:

```
IdCoche : Coche1 
IdConductor : Conductor1
```

y si quiero agregar ese mismo registro con diferente fecha, pues me permita volver a agregar:

```
IdCoche : Coche1 
IdConductor : Conductor1
```

Y asi sucesivamente, he intentado buscar alternativas pero no logro dar con algo.

Comment: Esta es la zona de respuestas, si requieres apoyo por favor lee [ask] y publica una nueva pregunta, posterior por favor eliminas esta *no respuesta*